# Automatically Switching Between HTTP and HTTPS asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl, https, webforms

I am in asp.net web forms paradigm (api implemented with APIController from MVC). I have added following bindings in IISExpress

```
http://sarfraz-pc:80
https://sarfraz-pc:443
```

using this [great article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/working-with-ssl-at-development-time-is-easier-with-iisexpress). I can access the entire site either using http or https. Now, I want to force some pages to run on http while other on https. Google gave me [lots of results](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=asp.net%20switch%20b/w%20http%20and%20https&rlz=1C1_____enPK456PK456&oq=asp.net%20switch%20b/w%20http%20and%20https&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=asp.net%20switch%20b/w%20http%20and%20https&hl=en&rlz=1C1_____enPK456PK456&prmd=imvnsfd&ei=FbP-T_C3CI3ysgb90on7AQ&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=673242acfd9407a3&biw=1366&bih=667) including a very [old solution from code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7206/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically-Ver) and the other one called [Security Switch](https://web.archive.org/web/20160601015855/https://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/).

But I am seriously considering using [IIS 7.0's url rewrite](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-rewrite-servervariables-url-parts-http-to-https-redirect-week-9) module to implement this. Has anybody used URL rewriting for this purpose? I don't know url rewriting in detail so I want to ask is there a drawback in taking this route? If yes, please suggest some alternative approach (including ones I mentioned) but it should not be simply writing the `Response.Redirect` code here and there in the application.

Comment: You cannot handle this with a server side redirect. The client must be redirected.

Comment: Marcus are you sure of this? I mean have you gone through http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/02/26/url-rewrite-servervariables-url-parts-http-to-https-redirect-week-9.aspx

Comment: For HTTPS, HTTP is layered on top of SSL/TLS. Once you start HTTP, it can't suddenly become HTTPS, or vice versa. It has to be a new connection, so the client must be involved.

Comment: In that video the speaker talks about 301 permanent redirect and I believe it is a client side redirect. no?

Comment: Correct, 301 is a client side redirect.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if those HTTPS pages are accessed by an authenticated user then you shouldn't be making *any* requests to HTTP. In fact the auth cookie should be marked secure to ensure it won't be sent over an insecure connection. More info: http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-9.html

Comment: I agree that auth cookie is nearly as important as user credentials themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Add this code to your global.asax file to inspect every request and convert on the fly.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
   {
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
+   HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 I don't know if the OP is looking for a global answer, but this demonstrates the proper method to detect if the connection is using HTTPS and if not, redirect. Though, it also allows local access without HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not using URL Rewrite (which I have only a small amount of experience with), we deal with it via custom errors in IIS.

- Set the custom error of "403.4" (SSL Required) to a URL such as "/Error/403_4.aspx".
- Set the directory/directories to "Require SSL".

Then have in `403_4.aspx`...

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim url As String = Request.Url.Query
  url = url.Replace("?403;", "")
  Dim port As String = String.Format(":{0}/", New Uri(url).Port)
  If url.IndexOf(port) <> -1 Then
    url = url.Replace(port, "/")
  End If
  url = url.Replace("http://", "https://")
  Response.Redirect(url, True)
End Sub
```

I know it's not exactly what you're after, but it's better than having the redirection in multiple places in the code.

Comment: you right: this is not what I am after. I would consider it if someone tells me that URL rewriting is not meant for this purpose

Comment: Not a problem @Muhammad, would be interested to see responses regarding URL Rewrite myself.